# Как удалить scss с компьютера?

Tags: npm, sass, scss, node-sass

Как мне решить такую проблему. В общем я делаю маленький проект на react, typescript и scss. Установил в самой папке проекта sass(scss) с помощью команды "npm i node-sass". После были некоторые проблемы с совместимостью node js и sass, которые я пробовал решить, но кажись сделал еще хуже. Теперь хочу удалить sass и попробовать начать делать все заново. Пробовал команды "npm uninstall node-sass" и "npm rebuild node-sass". Но все равно после них, когда смотрю версию sass с помощью команды "npm node-scss -v" она показывается (как понимаю это значить что ничего не удалено). Пробовал удалять проект и начинать все заново, но все равно в проекте показывается версия с помощью "npm node-scss -v". Так же даже если я выхожу из проекта она все равно показывается. Как понимаю это значит, что она устанавливается не только в папку с проектом, а прямо на компьютер. **Помогите пожалуйста как мне удалить sass?** Хочу начать все заново и уже правильно установить его.[вот консоль](http://joxi.ru/12MXgvKUwOaRvm)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> После были некоторые проблемы с совместимостью node js и sass

Действительно, такие проблемы довольно распространены. Скорее всего, дело в [этом](https://github.com/sass/node-sass#node-version-support-policy).

> Но все равно после них, когда смотрю версию sass с помощью команды "npm node-scss -v" она показывается

Вполне возможно, что некоторые зависимости или сам пакет установлены глобально. Во-первых, удаляйте его вручную путем удаления соответствующих строк в package.json и последующего `npm install`. Во-вторых, если пакет все же установлен глобально, то удаляйте его как

```
npm uninstall -g node-sass
npm uninstall node-sass
```

Если и это не поможет, то просто удалите директорию зависимости вручную.

Comment: Пакет установлен глобально. Попробовал данные выше команды, однако после все равно версия показывается http://joxi.ru/4AkdLjwC0G3Qgr , хотя я нахожусь за пределами проекта. Где мне найти зависимости и сам пакет что бы удалить их?

Comment: @fron321 зависит от окружения в котором работаете. Например у меня (GNU/Linux) это `/home/user/.npm`. И там под-папки с глобальными пакетами.